# Hardhat - How to get the block in timestamp in deployment file

Tags: javascript, ethereum, hardhat

I try to deploy my masterchef contract. I have 2 arguments to specify in the constructor (the token address and the actual block number in secondes). I use hardhat for doing this and I actually trying to get the value of the actuel block number in secondes ? How can I do this ?

```
const StakingRewards = await hre.ethers.getContractFactory("Masterchef");
const stakingRewards = await StakingRewards.deploy(token.address, block.timestamp);
```

Answer (score 14, accepted):

You can get the timestamp of the previous block like this:

```js
// getting timestamp
const blockNumBefore = await ethers.provider.getBlockNumber();
const blockBefore = await ethers.provider.getBlock(blockNumBefore);
const timestampBefore = blockBefore.timestamp;
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use the [time helpers](https://hardhat.org/hardhat-network-helpers/docs/reference#time-helpers) from the Hardhat Network Helpers library:

```js
const { time } = require('@nomicfoundation/hardhat-network-helpers');
const timestamp = await time.latest();
```